# iOS 10.1.1 and Safari 602.1 Causing redirect issues

Tags: ios, .net, iphone, ipad, safari

My team and I have been trying tirelessly to track down an issue that seems to be happening exclusively to iOS users. Our customer complaints seem to point to the software configuration mentioned in the title: iOS 10.1.1 using the Safari 602.1 build. The following user agents seem to be the most common:

Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 10_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14B100 Safari/602.1

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14B100 Safari/602.1

The issue being reported is as follows: customer enters credentials in an attempt to log in to our site, then they are redirected to the same login page.

From a web application perspective, we aren't logging any errors. So we've been using TeaLeaf to capture customer information and using the replay feature to help replicate the customer's interaction with our site. Even after using same software and hardware configuration (as much as possible), we still couldn't reproduce the issue.

The closest we came to reproducing the problem was to disable cookies before attempting to log in. Not being able to write to cookies on our site will bounce you back to the login page.

**My question is**: would anyone have any information about the iOS / Safari update that might cause similar issues? Any issues with the iOS update and cookies/cache on a .NET web application? Maybe something seemingly unrelated is manifesting itself differently on our site, so any information would be helpful!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more things I would check

1. Are they running a content blocker?
2. Are they running with website restrictions (General > Restrictions > Websites)?
3. Do they use any kind of enterprise device management software or non-standard profiles?

Comment: Thanks for the response! 
1) Some of our clients could be. Although, we just recieved a report from customer service letting us know that clearing cookies/cache helped one of our customers. 
2) Not likely. But I wouldn't think clearing cache/cookies could remedy such an issue. 
3) Not likely - These are consumer devices.